# gh actions cli - failed to set variable ...: HTTP 403: Must have admin rights to Repository

Tags: github-actions, pipeline

I tried to set a value to the repository variable RUN_ID with the gh actions cli:
below the code:

```
name: test3
on:
    workflow_dispatch:
      inputs:
        runid:
           required: false
           type: number

env:
   RUNID: ${{github['run_id']}}
   GITHUB_ENV: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
   GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}ß
         
jobs: 
    Test:
        permissions: write-all
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        environment: TWIST_DEV      
    
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3    
                
            - name: Display the input value
              run: |
                echo "${{env.runid}}"

            - name: Update environment file with 'run_id' value
              run: |
                echo "${{github['run_id']}}"  > file
                cat file

            - name: List directories
              run: |
                  ls -la      
            
            - name: Change mode to file
              run: chmod 777 file

            - name: List directories
              run: |
                  ls -la   

            - name: Inputs runid (workflow call)
              if: ${{ inputs.runid }} != ''
              run: 'gh variable set RUN_ID < file'


            - name: Set runid variable 
              run: echo "${{vars.runid}}"
```

When running manually the pipeline i got the below error message:

> **failed to set variable "RUN_ID": HTTP 403: Must have admin rights to Repository**

I will be enjoy i you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to [List environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/variables?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-environment-variables) and its related APIs, you need a PAT ([Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens)) with `repo` scope permissions (specifically, the `repo:public_repo` scope):

> You must authenticate using an access token with the `repo` scope to use this endpoint.

Once you have your PAT with the required scope then you need to set it to your environment secrets to be used by [GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) (`gh`).

Apart from that, in your workflow, you're using `environment`. To manipulate a variable in the environment, you need to specify `--env` or `-e` flag too. See [`gh variable list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_variable_list). Same goes for `set` and `delete` too.

Here's an example:

```yaml
name: gh_cli_variable_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: Dev

    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_VARIABLE_PAT }}
      TEST_VAR: 'test_var_value'
      TEST_VAR_ENV: 'test_var_value_env'

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Delete
        run: |
          gh variable delete TEST_VAR
          gh variable delete TEST_VAR_ENV --env Dev

      - name: List (repo)
        run: gh variable list

      - name: List (env Dev)
        run: gh variable list --env Dev

      - name: Set (repo)
        run: gh variable set TEST_VAR --body "$TEST_VAR"

      - name: Set (env Dev)
        run: gh variable set TEST_VAR_ENV --body "$TEST_VAR_ENV" --env Dev

      - name: List (repo)
        run: gh variable list

      - name: List (env Dev)
        run: gh variable list --env Dev

      - name: Dump
        run: |
          echo 'TEST_VAR: ${{ vars.TEST_VAR }}'
          echo 'TEST_VAR_ENV: ${{ vars.TEST_VAR_ENV }}'
```

Output:

[image: output]